# Invalidate form by custom component | AngularJS

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've searched my way, but can't figure this out. I made a directive `manyToOneSelect` (custom component) that loads items from the server, shows them to the user and lets the user pick one. That works well, but I cannot figure out how to prevent the form from being submitted if no item is picked by the user, i.e. how to invalidate the form.

Below is pretty much the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').
    directive('manyToOneSelect', function(entityService) {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            templateUrl:'partials/control/n21select.html',
            scope:{
                entityName:'@',
                entityField:'@',
                bindVariable:'='
            },
            compile:function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var inner = element.children("#n21select");
                    scope.entities = [];
                    scope.$watch('entityName', function ($new, $old) {
                        entityService.getList(scope.entityName, function (data) {
                            scope.entities = data;
                        }, []);
                    }, true);
                    scope.lookup = function(uuid) {
                        for(var i in scope.entities) {
                            if(scope.entities[i].uuid == uuid) {
                                return scope.entities[i];
                            }}}}}}});
```

Here is the corresponding partial `partials/control/n21select.html`:

```
<select ng-hide="disable" ng-options="entity.uuid as entity[entityField] for entity in entities" ng-model="bindVariable" required></select>
<span ng-show="disable">{{lookup(bindVariable)[entityField]}}</span>
```

Here is how I use the directive:

```
<form ng-href="#/" ng-submit="save()">
<many-to-one-select entity-name="customer" entity-field="name"
    bind-variable="entity.customerUuid"></many-to-one-select>
...
```

My problem seems lack of strategy, rather than "not entirely getting it to work", hence you don't see any attempt in the code I posted above. Let this be then a fairly open question: how to do it? :) Much appreciated already!

Comment: `}}}}}}});` ... AAAAHHH!!! MY EYES!!!

Comment: I did it like that so you can copy/paste the entire directive, without having to figure out how many brackets I omitted for the purpose of being brief :)

Comment: I was just teasing. I've added an answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this.

Considering how you've already built out the directive, one way is to add a scope attribute for the form itself. something like:

```
scope: {
   form: '='
}
```

Then you'd pass your form element in like so:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="whatever()">
   <my-directive-name form="myForm"></my-directive-name>
</form>
```

And in circumstance in your directive you wish to invalidate your form, you'd just call $setValidity on it:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
  if(somethingIsWrong) scope.form.$setValidity('reason', false);
}
```

**That's ONE way to do it, here's a *BETTER* way to do it if you can re-engineer your directive:**

The other way, which is probably preferred, is to have your directive require ngModel. Then you'll have more grainular control over your validation, as ngModel's controller will be passed in and you can use that to invalidate both your form, and a singular field on your form:

```
   app.directive('bettererWay', function() {
      return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         restrict: 'E',
         link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
             if(somethingIsBad()) ngModel.$setValidity('somethingIsBad', false);
         }
      };
   });
```

And that's how you do it, in a nutshell. Hopefully that gets you started in the right direction.

---

**EDIT: Weird issue with submission regardless of validity (in comments)**

This is apparently an issue caused by Angular trying to adhere to the HTML specs.

From the comments in their code [approx. line 214 here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js):

```
* To prevent double execution of the handler, use only one of ngSubmit or ngClick directives. This
 * is because of the following form submission rules coming from the html spec:
 *
 * - If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit
 * (`ngSubmit`)
 * - if a form has has 2+ input fields and no buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter
 * doesn't trigger submit
 * - if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or input[type=submit] then
 * hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the *first* button or
 * input[type=submit] (`ngClick`) *and* a submit handler on the enclosing form (`ngSubmit`)
```

So, given the above, it might be a good idea to have your directive tied to an input element of type hidden on the page rather than being it's own element. If you have more than one element on the form, invalidity prevents submission just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I went for the `bettererWay` and it works, in the sense that it properly affects the `formName.$isinvalid` flag, that I'm displaying for testing purposes along the `form` tag. However, I can still submit my form, whereas for other `required` form elements I can't...?!

Comment: weird, do you have a fiddle for that? The form ng-submit shouldn't fire if the form is $invalid.

Comment: I believe [this is a representative Fiddle for my situation](http://jsfiddle.net/P8M45/4/). Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Oh... it's the `ng-href="#/"` on your form tag that's doing it. If you remove that, the form doesn't submit. If it's a requirement that you send the form to a new location after submit, you can always inject `$location` into your controller, and call `$location.path('/')` in your submit function.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. If you only select something from the drop down and don't enter any text, it prevents submission just fine. Very strange. Also, you may want to start using Angular 1.0.5. You have 1.0.1 referenced there.

Comment: Yes, in the case of not entering text, you're using validation of an `input`. The oddity here seems to be that we're tying a non-`input` into the form (the `many-to-one-select` may have `input`s in its template, but it's not an `input` in its own right). Are you suggesting a bug in AngularJS or one in my code? :) The 1.0.1 reference came from my bumpy first steps in using Fiddle, but same results with 1.0.5 and 1.1.3. I may end up evaluating `$isinvalid` in my `save()` method and working around the issue for now.

Comment: Thank you. I see your point (pretty similar to my last pondering). And now I'm thinking `many-to-one-select` would be better off being an attribute of a `select` or other `input`. However, I'm starting with AngularJS while under some time pressure, so I may leave that exercise for a later time and help myself by having my `save()` method check the value of `$isinvalid` prior to proceeding. Nevertheless, thanks so much for your assistance!!!

Comment: Yes, and your help is really much appreciated too. Thinking some more about the matter, should we not somehow tell the form that it's a required item? (I.e. `required` or `ng-required`?) We now tell the form something is invalid -- it just sorta doesn't know what's wrong; or it may figure out by itself that, even though this one control isn't valid, the form as a whole is good to go?

Comment: $setValidity() has a first parameter that is a flag to let you know what happened. In our case we set it to "somethingIsBad". So if you checked the field like so: `{{formName.fieldName.$error.somethingIsBad}}` you'd get `true`. You can use this to display an error message with `ng-show`.  Having it be required is optional and a seperate issue, but you can do so if you choose.